# how to generate a UI fully dynamic? either MVC or WebForms

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I need to create a UI fully dynamically. The requirement is that there is about 100 controls on the page (possibly more), and as you fill the form out, the form itself changes. For example, when you fill out your age, if the age is over 30 but under 50, the next 3 questions will be different - if you are over 50, there will only be 2 questions and they will also be completely different. The page will continue to flow like this dynamically and the controls that are relevant to only you should should only appear with the questions as you answer them - obviously - as they might not be relevant to you and so we must keep them hidden until the last moment.

I can use either ASP.NET WebForms or MVC. I realize that MVC does not have the concept of a server control and this would need to be done using JS. I an open to using either technology I should note however, that this would be the first time developing an MVC application. I also have access to whichever 3rd party UI API that I'd like - Telerik, Component Art, Dev Express - I just need to get this working and have it be pretty.

What kind of approach would you do for generating this UI dynamically? Is there a design pattern / approach for this already that I may look at?

Comment: Rather than having them all on one page, have you considered a 'wizard' like approach - answer a gateway question and then get directed to a page with the next set of relevant questions?

Comment: I have considered this approach - however the business is requested it all be on a single page

Comment: All due respect to the business, but is it not better that they tell you what they need and you then tell them how you're going to do it?

Answer (score 1):

what you can do is, create each of the set of dynamic elements and put them in divs. depending on the answer now you can inject these divs in, or have then already lined up but hidden and make them visible at the correct answer. All of this logic will go into your controller and you just have to have a starting view, with an element which has `ID`.

```
document.getElementById(elementID)

if ((correctAnswer)&&(element.style.display=='none'))
   element.style.display="block"
```

Comment: can you possibly provide some psuedo code for what you're describing.. I'm not exactly a JS/HTML expert (I've been spoiled by WebForms all these years). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your index.html can have the following structure,

```
<html>
  <head.......
  ............
  ............
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <div id='staticFields1'>.....</div>
      <div id='staticFields2'>.....</div>
      <div id='dynamicFields21' display='none'>.....</div>
      <div id='dynamicFields22' display='none'>.....</div>
      <div id='staticFields3'>.....</div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

so based on your logic make display='block'

Comment: can you give more details? where would razor come in and how do i insert the controls dynamically? (sorry, years of WebForms has made by HTML/JS skills very poor)